# Hibernate ORM Provider, Netbeans 7, Glassfish (video)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have big problem with basic of the Hibernate in all my projects.

I have mysql server and there are a **hiber** database (localhost).
There are two tables: **messages** and **user**.

I have **Glassfish 3.1**.

I started new project in **Netbeans 7** with **Hibernate Framework**.
Then, I created entities and persistence.xml, PersistenceUnit.

After that, I created Servlet, ie. Demo (mapped as /Demo).

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Demo</title>");  
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet Demo at " + request.getContextPath () + "</h1>");

            EntityManagerFactory emf = 
                      Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("WebApplication7PU");
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

            em.getTransaction().begin();


            Message m = new Message(Integer.SIZE, 0, "Hello world");
            em.persist(m);


            em.getTransaction().commit();

            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            out.println("error: "+ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

**When I started my WebApp, I saw problem with EntityManagerFactory:**

> error: [PersistenceUnit:
>   WebApplication7PU] Unable to build
>   EntityManagerFactory

**What is a problem? I can't fix it :(**
. 
.

. 
--  MORE INFO --

**[This is a video on youtube with my problem](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DeSsC9Ec4I)**
.
.
.
.
Glassfish update center:
There are packages like JPA and Hibernate.

Glassfish log:

```
INFO: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: JNDI InitialContext properties:{}
INFO: Using datasource: hiberMysql
INFO: RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.1.53-community-log
INFO: JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.13 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )
INFO: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
INFO: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
INFO: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.ejb.transaction.JoinableCMTTransactionFactory
INFO: No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
INFO: Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
INFO: Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
INFO: JDBC batch size: 15
INFO: JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
INFO: Scrollable result sets: enabled
INFO: JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
INFO: Connection release mode: auto
INFO: Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
INFO: Default batch fetch size: 1
INFO: Generate SQL with comments: disabled
INFO: Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
INFO: Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
INFO: Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO: Query language substitutions: {}
INFO: JPA-QL strict compliance: enabled
INFO: Second-level cache: enabled
INFO: Query cache: disabled
INFO: Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
INFO: Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
INFO: Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
INFO: Statistics: disabled
INFO: Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
INFO: Default entity-mode: pojo
INFO: Named query checking : enabled
INFO: Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): disabled
INFO: building session factory
INFO: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
```

Persistnce.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="WebApplication7PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>hiberMysql</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hiber</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">haslo</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Are  you using a data source or the configuration parameter on your hibernate file? Because your persistence.xml is suggesting a data source named hiberMySQL, but this is not what your Hibernate configuration suggests.

Comment: First, I would look at Spring to handle your transactions because you have a bug in your code that if you throw and exception, you don't roll back the transaction, but rather just leave it open. Your catch or finally should be handling it. Here is a video showing the best practices and setup with Jpa and Spring: http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/spring-jpa-hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I see in logs:

```
INFO: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
```

JNDI indicates where javax.sql.DataSource is located. You have:

```
<jta-data-source>hiberMysql</jta-data-source>
```

I think you must change this to:
java:/hiberMysql

Comment: Thanks, this was a problem with JNDI.